# Can you solve this hard graph problem?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a connected, non directed, unweighted graph $G(V,E)$, let $S$ be a subset of $V$ such that each vertex in $V\setminus S$ is adjacent to at least one vertex in $S$.

The subset $S$ has to have the minimum cardinality (set size) possible.

What algorithm can you use to find this set $S$?

**Notation:**

- $G(V,E)$ = graph with node set V and edge set E.
- $V\setminus S =$ all other vertices that aren't in S.

*Disclaimer: Used to be a exam question. I'm not in the course anymore, but I still want to know the answer to this. So no, this is not a "homework question"*

Comment: Not sure it works, but naively I would try to put in $S$ a node $v_0$ of highest degree. Then if this is not sufficient, among the nodes that aren't connected to $v_0$, pick one $v_1$ of highest degree, and so on until your set $S = \{v_0, \ldots v_k\}$ has the desired property.

Comment: the naive $O(n^22^n)$ works for you? any specific bound?

Comment: What is the difference between your problem and minimum dominating set problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is known as [minimum dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set). It is well known to be NP-Hard problems so there is likely not an efficient algorithm to solve it. The wikipedia page I linked gives a reduction to and from set cover, which is one of Karp's famous NP-Complete problems.

As for algorithms, you can try what Phicar suggested, which would be to examine each possible vertex subset $S \subset V$ (there are $2^n$ such subsets) and check each $v \in V \setminus S$ to see if $v$ has a neighbor in $S$. This takes $O(2^nn)$ time. As far as theory goes, researchers in the field of exact algorithms have shown that there are algorithms for computing minimum dominating sets in roughly $O(1.5^n)$ time. I'm not aware of many practical algorithms for minimum dominating set besides perhaps integer programming formulations and smart branching heuristics.

There are better theoretical algorithms out there if you know you are working with a specific type of graph. For instance, there are fixed parameter tractable algorithms for planar graphs and, more generally, bi-clique free graphs. Greedy algorithms can give provable approximations as well. As I said before, I'm not aware of too many software packages that do this - I think it's mostly a theoretical question but let me know if you are interested in an integer programming formulation and I can add one as an edit.